# Wrap text in CSS (html) table cell to maintain least height

Tags: css, height, css-tables

I've a CSS table with two cells. Left one will contain text, and right one will contain images. The images will be of fixed size (let's say 120x120 pixels). I want to know if there is a way for the browser to calculate the widths of the columns so that the height of the whole table is always minimal. What I mean is the browser to shrink the left column so that the text wraps multiple lines until it becomes as tall as the image on the right, and only then start to increase the width of the left column.
Here is a sample code and link to jsfiddle:

```
<div id='container'>
<div class="table">
    <span id='cell1' class="cell-1">olympiad olympiad olympiad olympiad olympiad</span>
    <span id='cell2' class="cell-2"><img src='http://cdn1.askiitians.com/Images/2014619-143114257-7512-ff.png' alt='img'><img src='http://cdn1.askiitians.com/Images/2014619-143114257-7512-ff.png' alt='img'><img src='http://cdn1.askiitians.com/Images/2014619-143114257-7512-ff.png' alt='img'><img src='http://cdn1.askiitians.com/Images/2014619-143114257-7512-ff.png' alt='img'><img src='http://cdn1.askiitians.com/Images/2014619-143114257-7512-ff.png' alt='img'></span>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#container{
  width: 800px;  
}

.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.cell-1, .cell-2 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.cell-1 {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.cell-2 {
    line-height: 80px;
}

img{
  width: 120px; 
  height: 120px;
}
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/004brb6o/7/):

I want the text of the left to wrap so that the 5-th image can move to the 1-st row.

Comment: Yes, use an html table.

Comment: No...there isn't. There is no CSS property that would do that.